# react native realm error while generating apk

Tags: android, react-native, realm

I am trying to generate an apk file for my react native android app by running the command

`cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`

but I get the following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not list contents of '/Users/roman/Documents/Coding/Quotes/default.realm.note'.
```

Comment: It seems this problem has a discussion here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2743 - scroll down a bit.

Comment: I tried all the possible fixes but none seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone in the future who has this problem, I created an issue on github.

https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1012

Just delete the `realm.default.note` file in your root directory. If you can't see it in your finder window, view it in the terminal using the command `ls -a`